# How do I make fixed nav-bar with jQuery slidetoggle method push content down rather than overlap it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if someone out there could help me find a solution to this problem. I'm currently designing a responsive mobile web page and I currently have a fixed navigation bar on scroll with a jQuery slide-toggle method that expands the menu.

My issue is that when I click on the 'menu-trigger' button, instead of pushing the rest of the content down like I would want it to, the menu overlaps the content beneath it.

I've tried searching for answers here and elsewhere, but I couldn't find a definitive answer. I'm sorry if this has already been posted.

I didn't post any code on this post but here is a hypothetical jfiddle I made replicating the same exact issue. I hope someone can help, I'm ready to rip my hair out!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

  jQuery(".menu-bar ul").slideToggle();
  
 });

});
```

```css
/*For Scrolling Purposes*/
body {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}


.menu-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.menu-bar ul {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <!--Menu Bar Div-->
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu-trigger">
      <p>
        Button
      </p>
    </div><!--/Menu Trigger-->
      <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
      </ul>
  </div><!--/Menu Bar-->
  
  <!--Content Div-->
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/Content-->
  
</body>
```

Here is the jfiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/Lq7qqnn9/

Background: Pretty good with HTML and CSS not so much with javascript!

Comment: Position fixed elements don't follow normal layout so their children won't influence the rest of the page content. If the navigation was position relative then it would push content around. I assume you want the nav to follow you down the page? If so why would it need to push different content around depending on scroll position.

Comment: Hi Nick! Thanks for the reply. Yes you actually make a good point. At this point I'm trying different things and ran into this problem. Once I see how everything comes together I'll know whether to make changes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a placeholder item instead of a margin on your content. I.E. add a block behind your fixed block that maintains the height with it's fixed overlay.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

    $(".menu-placeholder").css("height", $(".menu-bar").height());
    jQuery(".menu-bar ul").slideToggle({
      progress: function() {

        $(".menu-placeholder").css("height", $(".menu-bar").height());
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
/*For Scrolling Purposes*/

body {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
) repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}
.menu-placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.menu-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
.menu-bar ul {
  display: none;
}
.content {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <!--Menu Bar Div-->
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <div class="menu-trigger">
      <p>
        Button
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/Menu Trigger-->
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/Menu Bar-->

  <!--Content Div-->
  <div class="menu-placeholder"></div>

  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
      <li>Some Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/Content-->

</body>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for that very fast answer!! You are awesome! I"m going to implement this in my code immediately. I literally spent the longest time trying to figure this out. I knew someone here would be able to help me out. Thanks you so much Tom!